# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (copy)

Tags: python, pyautogui, yolov5

i`m new to python and thank you for help.

I trained yolov5 mode to detect "zombie" and "ghost"

```
model = torch.hub.load('yolov5', 'custom', source='local', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp2/weights/best.pt')
while True: 
    screen = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,535, 1900, 475))
    corrected_colors = cv2.cvtColor(screen_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    results = model(corrected_colors)
    
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3zJC.png)

Its my first time

but i need to make left click on zombies

```
time.sleep(2)

while True: 
    screen = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,535, 1900, 475))
    screen_array = np.array(screen)
    corrected_colors = cv2.cvtColor(screen_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
    results = model(corrected_colors)
    
    df = results.pandas().xyxy
    df = df[df['class'] == 0]
    
    if df.empty:
        pass
    else:
        if df.iloc[0]['confidence'] > 0.60:
            xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = df.iloc[0]['xmin'], df.iloc[0]['ymin'], df.iloc[0]['xmax'], df.iloc[0]['ymax']
            center_x = int((xmin + xmax) / 2)
            center_y = int((ymin + ymax) / 2)
            pyautogui.click(center_x, center_y)
    
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but i have this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 11
      8 results = model(corrected_colors)
     10 df = results.pandas().xyxy
---> 11 df = df[df['class'] == 0]
     13 if df.empty:
     14     pass

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can someone give me advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: The error you're encountering is due to results not having a labels attribute. To resolve this issue, you'll need to check the documentation of the yolov5 library and the Detections object it returns to understand how to access the information you need (i.e. the detected object labels and their coordinates). Then modify your code accordingly.

Comment: i found that with results.pandas().xyxy[0] i can get  xmin ymin xmax ymax confidence class   name , if i understand right zombie in name is a label

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the list can be accessed through the indices of integer values [Python - Data Structures - List](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) A sample to understand the reason for this error is as follows,

```
a = ['{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}']
print(a['id'])
```

It will throw a Type error.

The apt way to access the list elements through using integer indices,

```
a = ['{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}']
print(a[0])
```

Output for the above code is as follows,

```
{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}
```

If you have list of dictionaries defined as follows, the appropriate way to access the elements in the list is as follows,

```
a = [{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}]
print(a[0]['id])
```

This will gives the output value of '9'